# Combine vendor chunk into chunk created with dynamic import in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using dynamic imports in a JS project with Webpack, and the chunks created from the dynamic imports have corresponding `vendors~[name].chunk.js` chunks. I'd like to include the vendors chunk inside the corresponding `[name].chunk.js`, i.e. not split it off into its own chunk.

webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
    output: {
        // ... 
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    },
}
```

app code:

```js
const Component = React.lazy(() =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "component" */ './Component')
);
```

produces

`vendors~component.chunk.js` and `component.chunk.js`

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. Do you mean that you would have only vendor chunk for the entire app instead of having each vendor connected to the each chunk?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit non-trivial because webpack will adjust your output based on the chunk file sizes specific to your project, but as a rule of thumb, this added to your webpack config will disable the seperatred vendor chunk:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks() {
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
```

This means what you currently see in `vendors~component.chunk.js` will be included in `component.chunk.js`.

it works by disabling split chunk behaviour, which by default is enabled on all async chunks, ie compontents using import().

See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks